# Intermittent MongoDB connection drop from Spring Microservice deployed in IBM code engine

Tags: mongodb

We are facing intermittent MongoDB connection drop from Spring Microservice deployed in IBM code engine.

Application.properties

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri= mongodb://uid:pwd@eb4e50bd-8373-4901-ac62-e910e154e91d-0.c4n4trid0tl3n7uvrtlg.databases.appdomain.cloud:30853,eb4e50bd-8373-4901-ac62-e910e154e91d-1.c4n4trid0tl3n7uvrtlg.databases.appdomain.cloud:30853,eb4e50bd-8373-4901-ac62-e910e154e91d-2.c4n4trid0tl3n7uvrtlg.databases.appdomain.cloud:30853/ibmclouddb?authSource=admin&ssl=true
spring.data.mongodb.socket-keep-alive=true
```

pom.xml

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
```

Application log

```
ov 29 22:13:03 Code Engine incident-management-00042-deployment-67d8fd47b9-vgr6w INFO 1 ---     [nio-8080-exec-1] c.i.e.i.c.IncidentManagementController   : Searching Incidents for user eapreqjn.ibm@bluemix.com
Nov 29 22:13:03 Code Engine incident-management-00042-deployment-67d8fd47b9-vgr6w INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.i.e.i.s.IncidentManagementService      : searchQueryForNewINC Search Query: Query: { "state" : "1"}, Fields: null, Sort: null
Nov 29 22:13:03 Code Engine incident-management-00042-deployment-67d8fd47b9-vgr6w WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Got socket exception on connection [connectionId{localValue:5, serverValue:266238}] to eb4e50bd-8373-4901-ac62-e910e154e91d-0.c4n4trid0tl3n7uvrtlg.databases.appdomain.cloud:30853. All connections to eb4e50bd-8373-4901-ac62-e910e154e91d-0.c4n4trid0tl3n7uvrtlg.databases.appdomain.cloud:30853 will be closed.
Nov 29 22:13:03 Code Engine incident-management-00042-deployment-67d8fd47b9-vgr6w INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:5, serverValue:266238}] to eb4e50bd-8373-4901-ac62-e910e154e91d-0.c4n4trid0tl3n7uvrtlg.databases.appdomain.cloud:30853 because there was a socket exception raised by this connection.
Nov 29 22:13:03 Code Engine incident-management-00042-deployment-67d8fd47b9-vgr6w INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.i.e.c.c.a.EAPortalControlerAdvice      : Handling ***** Exception *****
Nov 29 22:13:03 Code Engine incident-management-00042-deployment-67d8fd47b9-vgr6w INFO 1 --- [ain.cloud:30853] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Discovered replica set primary eb4e50bd-8373-4901-ac62-e910e154e91d-0.c4n4trid0tl3n7uvrtlg.databases.appdomain.cloud:30853
Nov 29 22:13:03 Code Engine incident-management-00042-deployment-67d8fd47b9-vgr6w ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.i.e.c.c.a.EAPortalControlerAdvice      : Prematurely reached end of stream; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream
org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Prematurely reached end of stream; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:107) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.7.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:2146) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.7.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:484) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.7.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.count(MongoTemplate.java:777) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.7.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.count(MongoTemplate.java:758) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.7.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at com.ibm.eamp.incident.service.IncidentManagementService.getIncidentPage(IncidentManagementService.java:737) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.ibm.eamp.incident.service.IncidentManagementService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$bb6f10b3.invoke(<gener
```

we have tried with adding timeout property but it did not resolve the issue

> spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://ibm_cloud_8194d370_6773_45a9_b1b2_3161e24df687:41f6b441998e56690102c0549f32536f4642ed3133448d2b39fdd7b795d5850a@eb4e50bd-8373-4901-ac62-e910e154e91d-0.c4n4trid0tl3n7uvrtlg.databases.appdomain.cloud:30853,eb4e50bd-8373-4901-ac62-e910e154e91d-1.c4n4trid0tl3n7uvrtlg.databases.appdomain.cloud:30853,eb4e50bd-8373-4901-ac62-e910e154e91d-2.c4n4trid0tl3n7uvrtlg.databases.appdomain.cloud:30853/ibmclouddb?authSource=admin&socketTimeoutMS=360000&connectTimeoutMS=360000&ssl=true

Comment: Going out on a limb here but it sounds like the IBM Code Engine / Spring environment (serverless deployment) is shutting down before mongodb gets to read or write everything it needs.  The `timeout` property you are setting is for socket connections, not abrupt closing by the host environment.   Look for a property like "socket close delay" in IBM Code Engine.   Maybe this?  https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/codeengine?topic=codeengine-faqs    10 minute max connection time

Comment: thanks for the response let me check and get back.

Comment: I could find only a scale-down delay for the autoscaling setup. which is not effective in our case we set the min and max instance as 1 in the autoscale configuration

Comment: how can I add a screenshot here?